# How do you plot multiple columns of a data frame all within the same boxplot in r (using ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Train_Table_Time_Power <- data.frame(
Mean = runif(100),
STD = runif(100),
Kurt = runif(100),
Skew = runif(100),
  TI = sample(c("0.05", "0.10", "0.15", "0.20"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I then created a box for the Skew Feature using the code below:

```
Skew_BoxPlot <- ggplot(Train_Table_Time_Power, aes(x = TI, y = Skew, color = TI)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = T, id=TRUE) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="point", shape=19, color="red", size=2) +
  geom_jitter(shape=16, position = position_jitter(0.2), size = 0.3) +
  labs(title = "Crest_Time", x = "TI", y = "Normalized Magnitude") +
  theme_minimal() + theme_Publication()
```

The above box plot displays the different distributions of the Skew feature as the TI feature varies. However, I now want to create a new box plot that shows the distributions of all of the features (Mean, STD, Kurt, and Skew) for just one value of TI, say TI = 0.05, and I would like the figure to plot all of the box plot distributions on the same graph horizontally, next to each other. Can anyone direct me on how best to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your data into a long table and then plot. Using tidyverse this can be easily done

```
library(tidyverse)
Train_Table_Time_Power %>% filter(TI == 0.05) %>% 
pivot_longer( cols=1:4) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

You can change `TI == 0.05` to any value that you want or you can do all TI values and used `facet_grid()` to split out individual plots

```
Train_Table_Time_Power  %>% pivot_longer( cols=1:4) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() +facet_grid(~TI)
```